# Cast generic ChildFolder<SomeType> to ChildFolder<object>?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have a generic type which is basically a wrapper for another class (for serialization purposes), `ChildFolder<SomeType>`.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ChildFolder<T>
    {
        public T value;
    }
```

I have a reference to a ChildFolder<> which is currently type `object`. I need to be able to access that object's .value, no matter what T is - getting it as an `object` is perfect. I was hoping that generic types would follow the heritability rules of the parameter class, so that this would work:

```
object obj = new ChildFolder<SomeClass>(); // (this is equivalent to what's coming in to the function as a parameter)

ChildFolder<object> chObj = (ChildFolder<object>)obj;
// and now chObj.value is of type object
```

But this line gives me `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

How can I typecast to ChildFolder if I don't know what the `<T>` is? Alternately, how can I access .value without typecasting it?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've solved the problem by creating a non-generic base class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ChildFolder<T> : ChildFolderBase
    {
        public T value
        {
            get
            {
                return (T)valueAsObject;
            }
            set
            {
                valueAsObject = value;
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator T(ChildFolder<T> cf)
        {
            return cf.value;
        }
    }

    public class ChildFolderBase
    {
        public object valueAsObject;
    }
```

I can easily cast to ChildFolderBase and get .valueAsObject.